# Apply category to a framework class

Tags: ios, parse-platform, uiimageview, sdwebimage, objective-c-category

What I want to achieve is to enable the `PFImageView` class (from Parse framework) respond to `SDWebImage` methods. `SDWebImage`is a framework in itself, but since it essentially applies a category to `UIImageView` - and `PFImageView` inherits from `UIImageView` - it seems that it should be possible to achieve this.

I tried creating a separate category `PFImageView+SDWebImage`, where in the .h file I simply added

```
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>
```

but this is clearly not enough as I still receive an crash with an error saying `[PFImageView setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:completed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`.

How does one achieve what I'm trying to do here correctly?

Comment: Why ur using SDWebImage Framework ?? I know its use for Image display in list formate etc. but wanted to know from point of view

Comment: I'm using SDWebImage to asynchronously load and display images for contacts from Facebook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A category properly applied to `UIImageView` will automatically be available to subclasses. You don't need to do anything special. And your header shouldn't matter at all. Headers don't apply categories; they just tell the compiler that they exist so you won't receive warnings. Categories are applied when the relevant implementations are loaded (specifically they happen when the `+load` method is called, but in the iOS world you can think of this as "when the program starts.")

All that suggests that you're just not loading your category code at all. That's a very common problem. Make sure that you're compiling the relevant `.m` file that implements this category, and make sure that if you're linking this from a static library, that you're using the `-ObjC` flag. See [QA1490](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1490/_index.html) for full details. The short version is that if you put category code in a static library, the linker may see it as unused and strip it. The `-ObjC` flag tells the compiler that this is the <strike>crazy</strike> awesome dynamic ObjC world and sometimes things that don't look like they're used actually are.

Comment: Rob, I don't (think I) use static libraries in my project, I have added `SDWebImage` as a framework as per default recommendations. I only #import `SDWebImage` in the class where I intend to use it. Should I use it somehow differently?

Comment: Did you follow the "Add Linker Flag" in the SDWebImage instructions? https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage#add-linker-flag

Comment: You were right, -ObjC flag is all it took to fix my problem. Thank you